# jQuery to stop a function using click, that runs on doc ready - Then start function when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page that has 2 functions that begin on document ready. One begins a slideshow of images fading in and out and another that slowly fades a background image in and out. I have implemented a switch that when clicked, fades in a new background image and overall background-color. I'm trying to figure out how to have this switch also stop the functions that are running on document ready (or disable them completely so the slides aren't sitting still) but also restart them when clicked again. So basically toggle the functions each time clicked. I mocked up a page that has images cycling and a button to change the image and background color (I left off the other function I mentioned to make it less complicated and more clean). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. 
I've looked into adding a global variable and then an if-statement for the functions and then have the click change that global to an invalid, then I tried looking into toggle-functions but had no luck. I'm fairly new to all of this so I apologize if my code is messy or confusing

http://jsfiddle.net/timtim123/d6xn8/2/

```
<body>
    <img src="http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/background_zps3f866162.png" id="backimg" />
    <div id="switch">
        <img src="http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/darkswitch_zpsc7190818.png" width="46" height="275" border="0" />
    </div>
    <div class="fadein">
        <img src="http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/slide1_zps169c4a26.png" width="394" height="630" border="0" />
        <img src="http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/slide2_zps72fbcc61.png" width="394" height="630" border="0" />
        <img src="http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/slide3_zpsaf2fb393.png" width="394" height="630" border="0" />
        <img src="http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/slide4_zps9544ea88.png" width="394" height="630" border="0" />
    </div>
</body>

body {
    background:black;
    transition:background 0.2s ease;
}
.clicked {
    background:white;
}
#backimg {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#backimg2 {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
#switch {
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 300px;
    height:275px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 7;
}
.fadein {
    position:absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:630px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 500px;
}
.fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 500px;
}


//cycle through slides
$(document).ready(function cycle() {
    timer = $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(2000)
            .next('img').fadeIn(2000)
            .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    }, 2000);

    //switch functionality    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#switch").click(function () {
            var src = $("#backimg").attr("src");
            $("body").delay(2000).queue(function () {
                $("body").toggleClass("clicked");
                $("body").dequeue();
            });


            if (src == "http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/background_zps3f866162.png") {
                $("#backimg").fadeOut(2000, (function () {

                    $("#backimg").fadeIn(2000).attr("src", "http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/background2_zps36c1126d.png");
                }));


            } else if (src == "http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/background2_zps36c1126d.png") {
                $("#backimg").fadeOut(500, (function () {
                    $("#backimg").delay(5000).fadeIn(5000).attr("src", "http://i1331.photobucket.com/albums/w600/timtim123454/background_zps3f866162.png");
                }));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try doing it using `clearInterval` as in the example shown at the top of this page http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp. This will stop the setInterval function.

2) To hide your slideshow / image you will need to use jQuery hide. Stopping a function will not change elements in the DOM.

3) Here is an elaboration on the code in the link I sent you, that includes stop and start functionality.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A script on this page starts this clock:</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myStopFunction()">Stop time</button>
<button onclick="myStartFunction()">Stop time</button>

<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer()
{
  var d = new Date();
  var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t;
}

function myStopFunction()
{
  clearInterval(myVar);
}

function myStartFunction()
{
  myVar = setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if you need further information.

FYI - you don't need 2 '$(document).ready' Just put the code of the 2nd one under the code of the 1st one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I didn't think of just hiding the slideshow class and then showing it when I want it back. I was actually able to get this working by adding in    $(".fadein").toggle(); in the click function, which I like because it lets the slides keep rolling while hidden. I just need to work on stopping the other function that I had (not in my example). I'll check out what you sent tonight and see if I can figure it out.  Thanks